# AVD is up and running but eclipse doesnt detects

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

My AVD is running properly and in the process tab, there's an emulator-arm.exe so i'm pretty sure about it but when i run my program with a run configuration that says to pick up this AVD, i get the following message.

```
Android Launch!
[2015-02-15 00:38:50 - FirstApp] adb is running normally.
[2015-02-15 00:38:50 - FirstApp] Performing com.protyay.example.firstapp.Splash activity launch
[2015-02-15 00:38:50 - FirstApp] No active compatible AVD's or devices found. Relaunch this configuration after connecting a device or starting an AVD.
```

This is the Manifest.xml looks like, and as a matter of fact, i have had absolutely no problems testing this app until yesterday. A strange problem

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.protyay.example.firstapp.MAINACTIVITY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

API level for AVD is 19

Comment: What's your AVD device api level configuration? Also, how is your FirstApp's AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @alijandro Please do find the edited Question for references. Thank You! :)

Comment: What's your `android:minSdkVersion` in your AndroidManifest.xml, in order to let it run your AVD, it should be smaller than 19.

Comment: yeah, it's API level 14. No problem there.

Comment: @alijandro Oh Problem solved. I have tried re-launching the AVD with ' Launch from Snapshot ' un-checked and that worked like a breeze. :)

Comment: It is not related to snapshots FYI, this happens a lot with ADB.  Changing that selection just reset your AVD

Answer (score 0):

Try to this, It may be a helpful
Go To Window->Show View->Others->Device->Reset Adb

Answer (score 0):

Reset your ADB process.  You can do that within the DDMS Perspective (then the Devices window).  T he last menu on the right  (the upside down triangle - on the main 'devices' panel - the one that 'should' show your device in the list) has this option in there - it is named 'Reset ADB'.

Also, you can do this following from the command-line:

```
1. adb kill-server
2. adb start-server
```

Comment: hey thanks everyone!! :) I have actually mentioned that i have launched it with the 'Launch from Snapshot' menu unchecked and it worked. 
I think that's equivalent to resetting but not sure!